# Buzzing Noise when watching Videos on HP Laptop

Tags: video, touchpad, hp-pavilion, noise

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04
Hardware: HP Pavilion 15-eg0778ng
```

My Laptop is making buzzing high frequency noise, whenever I start playing a video.

- Having the charger plugged in or not does not make a difference.
- The sound is there whenever I start a video, it does not matter if I mute audio or
  plug in headphones, so it is probably unrelated to the speakers.
- The sound stops around 5-10 seconds after pausing a video.
- It also stops when I touch the touchpad and restarts once I remove my finger.

Comment: could it be a fan?

Comment: My guess would be that this is probably a result of poor shielding and or grounding.  I add grounding because you mention that it stops when you touch the touchpad.  When you play a video, I would ***guess*** that a hardware component get enabled causing the interference.  I too have had problems like this over the years with various motherboards.  Again.. this is just a guess.  To test my theory, try USB headphones as they are their own sound source and shouldn't pick up signals from the mobo.  Does the problem go away?  I hope you get it figured out. :)